# xfs: writing to 17TB offset doesn't actually write it to specified offset

Tags: sparse-files

I have a situation wherein I want to write a few GBs at a very large offset - say 17TB. But when I use the dd command to do so, I notice that the filesystem is doing some kind of optimization - sparse file - and it doesn't really write at that offset - but tells me that it did. Filling up 17TB would be very very time consuming - so I'm looking for ways wherein I can write at the desired offset.

I have partitioned the disk as one partition only using xfs and mounted on centOs.

Comment: What counts as "writing at the desired offset" to you?

Comment: If you actually want to reserve 17TB of space, `fallocate` might help.

Comment: Well, it actually *does* write at that offset and reports correctly. You can't have a non-sparse file and save yourself writing the starting 17TB.

Comment: Thanks frostschutz for the suggestion. I tested out fallocate - even though it shows used space as 16TB (I had to create 16 files, looks like it can only allocate 1TB at a time), when I write at 17TB offset, it still goes to the lower offsets.

Comment: HI Michael Homer - I want to write at a higher offset, >16TB